How to show Einstein Activity Capture Outlook Events into Custom Reports and Dashboards in Enterprise Salesforce Org
I want to get Outlook events captured by Salesforce's Einstein Activity Capture into custom reports and dashboards within our enterprise Salesforce organization.
Through my research, it seems that utilizing Activity 360 reports can achieve this goal. However, it's necessary to purchase licenses such as Sales Cloud Einstein, Sales Engagement, or Revenue Intelligence for enterprise organizations to access Activity 360 reports. Could anyone advise on which license would be most effective for this requirement, or if there are any alternative solutions available?
